# Almost complete unit in ring proof.

Tags: abstract-algebra

the set $ R= \{ i+j \sqrt 3 | i,j \in \mathbb {Z} \}$ is ring ( have proved this already.

Show if i and j are not relatively prime $ i+j \sqrt 3 $ is not a unit. (this part is childs play by contradiction)

Show that $ i+j \sqrt 3 $ is a unit iff $i^2 - 3j^2 = \pm 1 $

I have managed to show this with a shitty argument by cases but by doing part of anther question with this ring relating to its quotient group i have found most of a much more elequiant solution to this.

Finish the following proof:

let $ b \in R $ define $ b= i+j \sqrt 3 $ and define $b^{'} = i-j \sqrt 3 $
then $bb^{'} = i^2 - 3j^2 $ define this to be N(b) where N is the norm of b.

since $i^2 - 3j^2 \in \mathbb {Z} $ it implies that $ N(b) \in \mathbb {Z} $
now the only units of $\mathbb {Z} = \pm 1$ so N(b) is a unit for $\mathbb {Z}$ iff $N(b) = \pm 1$ this implies $i^2 - 3j^2$ is unit for $\mathbb {Z}$ iff $i^2 - 3j^2= \pm 1$

My problem is im missing the last piece. i need b is a unit in the ring iff N(b) is a unit for $\mathbb {Z}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that $N(bb')=N(b)N(b')$. So if $b$ is a unit, there exists $b'$ such that $bb'=1$ we deduce that $N(b)N(b')=1$, since $N(b), N(b')\in \mathbb{Z}$ we deduce that $N(b)=1$ or $N(b)=-1$.

$N(b)$ is the norm here, $N(b)i+ \sqrt3 j=i^2-3j^2$.

Comment: sorry i thought i had it but when i went to write it out i realized it still didn't make any sense what does your N(b) do cause i defined N(b) to do something specific and i don't think its doing what yours is.